# What does "roundaboutness" in economic mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Today I face a term "[roundaboutness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundaboutness#:%7E:text=Roundaboutness%2C%20or%20roundabout%20methods%20of,desired%20consumer%20goods%20are%20produced.)" from some [papers](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09538259.2014.957475).I still cannot understand the meaning of such a word, could you please help me to clarify it. It is awesome if there is any example for this word.

Comment: I think you have an explanation and an example in your link.  What is not clear from the Wikipedia page.  Note that this is not a standard word in English, it is jargon that is only used in economics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wiki says, it is a process when capital goods are produced first and then, with the help of the capital goods, the desired consumer goods are produced.

Thus, gasoline will be produced and marketed if the demand for such fuel is sufficient to make oil production and processing profitable.

Comment: so, does it mean that company will decide to produce goods based on the known (or guessed) demand, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.